# Joomla! 2.5 backend component adapted to Joomla! 3.3: Toolbar has stopped working

Tags: component, fix-my-code, upgrade

While adapting a Joomla!2.5 backend-only component to Joomla!3.3, I've ran into the issue of the toolbar in the data edition page not working at all. Only two buttons were declared: Save and Cancel; neither do anything. Upon first glance, the problem is neither on the *view.html.php* file, nor *tmpl/edit.php*. This very component is already being used in our current Joomla!2.5 website and works perfectly.

All control, model and view pages have already been updated to *JControllerLegacy*, *JModelLegacy* and *JViewLegacy* respectively, where applicable. Server settings' error reporting has already been set to Maximum, but there's no error or warning showing.

***view.html.php***

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
jimport('joomla.application.component.viewlegacy');

class MrCarrosselNoticiasViewMrCarrosselNoticias extends JViewLegacy {
    function display($tpl = null){
        $form = $this->get('Form');
        $item = $this->get('Item');
        if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors'))){
            JError::raiseError(500, implode('<br />', $errors));
            return false;
        }
        $this->form = $form;
        $this->item = $item;
        $this->addToolBar();
        parent::display($tpl);
    }

    protected function addToolBar(){
        $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        $input->set('hidemainmenu', true);
        $isNew = ($this->item->cod_destaque == 0);
        JToolBarHelper::title($isNew ? "Novo Destaque" : "Editando Destaque");
        JToolBarHelper::save('mrcarrosselnoticias.save');
        JToolBarHelper::cancel('mrcarrosselnoticias.cancel', 'JTOOLBAR_CANCEL');
    }
}
```

***tmpl/edit.php***

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted Access');
JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');
JHtml::_('behavior.modal');
?>

<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mrcarrosselnoticias&layout=edit&cod_destaque='.(int) $this->item->cod_destaque); ?>" method="post" name="adminForm" id="mrcarrosselnoticias-form">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.startTabSet', 'myTab', array('active' => 'details')); ?>
        <?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.addTab', 'myTab', 'details', 'Detalhes do Destaque'); ?>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span9">
                <?php echo $this->form->getControlGroup('imagem'); ?>
                <?php echo $this->form->getControlGroup('titulo'); ?>
                <?php echo $this->form->getControlGroup('desc'); ?>
                <?php echo $this->form->getControlGroup('link'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.endTab'); ?>
        <?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.endTabSet'); ?>
    </div>

<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="mrcarrosselnoticias.edit" />
    <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Since you are asking for help to fix a problem rather than a code review, I have migrated the question to the Joomla! site.

Comment: Did you check the browser console for any errors? Can you post your edit.php?

Comment: _edit.php_ added to main post. Also, yes, checked console... Nothing out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this scenario when troubleshooting back-end component functionality.  9 times out of 10 its because I didn't include the JavaScript logic to handle the toolbar tasks.  Try adding the below script above the form.  Once added, the toolbar call to action buttons should start working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Joomla.submitbutton = function(task)
    {
        if (task == 'mrcarrosselnoticias.cancel' || document.formvalidator.isValid(document.id('mrcarrosselnoticias-form'))) {
            Joomla.submitform(task, document.getElementById('mrcarrosselnoticias-form'));
        }
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad I could help!